# Value expected to be a string, float, or int instead of an empty tuple

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros2, urdf, moveit

I've been trying to export a model from SolidWorks to URDF, I have made the necessary changes, as far as configuring the files. The model shows perfectly fine on MoveIt setup assistant and I generate the necessary files accordingly.

However, no matter what I do I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback):
 Expected 'value' to be one of [<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'bytes'>], but got '()' of type '<class 'tuple'>'
```

At first, I assumed the value they are referring to has to do with the value of the mass in the URDF. Unfortunately, the value already is a `float`. So, I don't understand what exactly is going on. The debug tool did not help too. I also compared my files with those of panda's Github repo and they're identical in a sense.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide the link to the "panda's Github repo", as there are quite a few and it *might* not be very clear about which repo you are referring to. Also, when you say "they're identical in a sense", do you mean "they're identical in *every* sense"?

Comment: When you `(see debug for traceback)` does it give you a line number for where it's having the problem? What exists at that line? Can you please *edit your question* to provide the file you're using?